# How do I remove unnecessary versions of node in Centos

Tags: centos, package-management, node.js, npm

I am trying to learn how to use node.js in centos 8

I have installed node.js and npm, and using npm I have installed inherits and n

I have been following tutorials on different websites and have been installing various node.js based software on this computer, and I managed to have two versions on node.js installed on this computer

I normally use this computer as the user 'username', and going to a terminal and typing node -v as 'username' gives me

```
v12.16.3
```

However, if I type in sudo node -v, I get

```
v10.21.0
```

I think that this is a mistake and I should only have v12.16.3 installed, and I don't know how I ended up doing this. How do I keep v12.16.3 and delete other versions of node? If it is safe for them to coexist, how do I make sudo use the v12 version of node?

EDIT:

I believe the v12.16.3 version is installed at `/usr/local/bin/node` and the v10.21.0 is at `/bin/node` but I don't know how this ended up happening. If I understand correctly, `/usr/local/bin/` is similar to Window's `Program Files` but for programs installed for my current user, while `/bin/` is like the root user's `Program Files`? Is this a good way to understand this? I'm not sure what I did to have a lower version of node.js to also get installed, but I don't think I need this version. Issuing `sudo yum list installed` only shows me a single `nodejs.x86_64` entry. Does Centos have equivalent of Window's Add/remove program list that clearly lists what programs I have installed?

Comment: If you have only installed packages via `yum` you can use `yum history list` to show the transactions, and then inspect them, this may help you understand when/how you got the other version.  You can also use `yum provides /usr/local/bin/node` to see if a `yum` installed package is responsible for the second `node` version

Comment: @einfeyn496 `sudo yum provides /usr/local/bin/node` gives me `Error: no matches found`

Comment: @einfeyn496 `sudo yum history list | grep node` gives me a single entry for `install nodejs`

Comment: @einfeyn496 I have enabled epel-release and installed things using npm, but as far as I understand I initially installed node using yum

Comment: It appears then that the `/usr/local/bin/node` version was installed via another means than the `yum` package manager (possibly via `npm install node`?), and in this case, you have to set the environment to use the non-`yum` installed version (you should probably see that your user account has `/usr/local/bin` in the `PATH` variable if you do `echo $PATH`).

Comment: Since you mention that you're using CentOS 8, you might also consider taking advantage of the App Stream and Modules features present in the OS.  They are designed to select, system wide, different versions of certain packages (`nodejs` is one).  You may find https://docs.centos.org/en-US/8-docs/managing-userspace-components/assembly_using-appstream/#application-streams_using-appstream and https://docs.centos.org/en-US/8-docs/managing-userspace-components/assembly_introduction-to-modules/ helpful, since it sounds like your goal is just to have a more up-to-date version of `nodejs` installed

Comment: @einfeyn496 `/usr/local/bin` is indeed in the PATH variable and it's possible I might have done `npm install node` at some point